# SharePoint 2013 Server 500 Error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, error, certification

Two of the certificates for my servers expired today and everything went down hill after that.  I had this same issue last year, however the person that fixed it for me wasn't even sure what he had done that solved the issue.  I saved the link of the steps that he followed, however there is a completely different article on that page.

My main issue stems from the fact that I don't know how the trust is established among the servers.  I don't know which server should generate the trust certificate or even if there is a special way to generate it.  I tried to do it on my own however I am still getting a Server 500 error and a tons of errors in the event logs for both servers.  Below is the error I am getting for Event ID 3:

> WebHost failed to process a request.  Sender Information:
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/12036987 
>   Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service
>   '/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc' cannot be
>   activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception
>   message is: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..
>   ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   certificate    at
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken..ctor(X509Certificate2
>   certificate, String id, Boolean clone, Boolean disposable)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPSecurityTokenServiceManager.ConfigureTokenHandlerCollection(SPSecurityTokenServiceManager
>   manager, SecurityTokenHandlerCollectionManager collectionManager,
>   String key, SecurityTokenHandlerCollection& tokenHandlerCollection)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration.ConfigureTokenHandlerCollectionForLocalIssuer(SPSecurityTokenServiceManager
>   manager, SecurityTokenHandlerCollectionManager collectionManager,
>   String key)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration..ctor()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder
>   binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr,
>   Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes)    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type,
>   BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo
>   culture)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustServiceHostFactory.CreateSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration(String
>   constructorString)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String
>   constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPSecurityTokenServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String
>   constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo
>   serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String
>   relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)  Process
>   Name: w3wp  Process ID: 8008

The part that jumped out at me is where it said that the certificate is null.  How do I set that?  Can someone point me in the article that tells me how to set this up?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out and I am posting this just in case anyone else has the same issue.  I had to run the below in PowerShell (please note that this is done after you create the certificate):

```
$pfxPath = "<path to replacement certificate (.pfx file)>"
$pfxPass = "<certificate password>"
$stsCertificate = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 $pfxPath, $pfxPass, 20
Set-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig -ImportSigningCertificate $stsCertificate
certutil -addstore -enterprise -f -v root $stsCertificate
iisreset
net stop SPTimerV4
net start SPTimerV4
```